# Golang - Package - Template Engine with Caching

Tags: caching, redis, package, go, template-engine

I have been looking for a template engine with caching but haven't had any luck. I have considered implementing my own system using Redis and my current template engine Pongo.

My plan was to create a folder containing all the templates that would be part of the config so there were no limitations on others and each template would be loaded onto Redis when the file is updated compared to the Redis time stamp for the template.

I was also considering a check on the templates request so if you edit a template a lot but it isn't requested as often the server isn't loading it for all saves. This minimizes the work without drastically affecting many requests.

Is anyone aware of a template caching package for Go?
If not is the caching method described a decent option or is there a better option I should implement instead?